# Create a column based on condition pertaining to 2 other columns

Tags: python, pandas, vector, dataframe

I have two columns in a pandas DataFrame (let's call the 'col1' and col2'). Both contain True/False values.

I need to create a third column from these two ('col3'), that will have a True value for a record if one or the other of the two columns has a True value in that record.

Currently, I'm doing this with:

```
col3 = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if df.ix[index, 'col1'] == True or df.ix[index, 'col2'] == True:
        col3.append(True)
    else:
        col3.append(False)

df['col3'] = col3
```

It works fast enough for the size of my dataset, but is there any way to do it in a one-liner/vectorized way? Perhaps using two nested `np.where()` statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`np.logical_or`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_or.html) to do this:

```
In [236]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[True,False,False], 'col2':[False,True,False]})
df

Out[236]:
    col1   col2
0   True  False
1  False   True
2  False  False

In [239]:
df['col3'] = np.logical_or(df['col1'], df['col2'])
df

Out[239]:
    col1   col2   col3
0   True  False   True
1  False   True   True
2  False  False  False
```

or use `|` operator:

```
In [240]:
df['col3'] = df['col1'] | df['col2']

df
Out[240]:
    col1   col2   col3
0   True  False   True
1  False   True   True
2  False  False  False
```