# What is the cleanest way to use truth operations on multiple Pandas series?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I currently have two bool pandas.series objects. They are derived from the same source so I have no worries about indexing etc.

What I need to do is combine them within an **or** truth table;

ie) 
    T T = T 
    T F = T 
    F T = T 
    F F = F

What is the cleanest way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is identical to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38096144/create-a-column-based-on-condition-pertaining-to-2-other-columns just posted before yours

Comment: ah thanks, not sure that had been posted when I submitted